# Problemas ao importar imagens em .sass

Tags: css, front-end, sass, scss

Estou com um problema estranho para importar imagens.

```
.banner{
    background: url(../../imagens/banner.jpeg);
}
```

No formato acima funciona corretamente em um arquivo .scss

Mas em um arquivo .sass não funciona quando faço na forma abaixo

```
.banner
    background: url(../../imagens/banner.jpeg)
```

Alguém saberia me explicar o motivo? Desde já agradeço, ótimo dias a todos

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Acabei de fazer mais uns tentes e consegui converter o .scss pronto pro formato .sass e funcionou, mas uma função que existe qnd esta em .scss não está funcionando q é mostrar as pastas conforme vou digitando a url

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).